# Arraylist add method into last value every item

Tags: java, android

```
for(int i=1; i <= allsize; i+=10) {
    all[c] = new All();
    mPremiumList.clear();

    if(pre_size != 0){
        if(pre_order < pre_size){
            mPremiumList.add(premiumArrayList.get(pre_order));
            pre_order++;
        }
    }

    all[c].setPremiumItemsInSection(mPremiumList);
    mAllList.add(all[c]);
    c++;
}
```

mAllList have last value every item..
I try this code include for

```
All all = new All();
```

but still add method into last value every item..
what i missing?

Comment: `mPremiumList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: If you want folks to take the time to study your code and help solve your problem, please put in the time to format your code so that it's easy to read. If we can readily read your code, we have a better chance of understanding it, no?

Comment: Code formatted for you

Comment: Java only has primitive and reference variables. When you add a List to a collection you are adding that reference not a copy of the list. You should be able to see this in your debugger.